# many-to-many: has_many :through association form with data assigned to linking model create form view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, nested-forms, has-many-through

I'm playing with an example from Rails Guides:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

This example has the following setup for the models:

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, :through => :appointments
end
```

I'm trying to understand how to do the following two things:

1. How do I setup the view that would create a new Patient and assign an Appointment to them  with an existing Physician with an Appoint Time
2. How do I assign an existing Patient an Appointment with a new Physician and an Appointment Time

I went through the RailsCasts 196 & 197 that deal with nested forms, but I don't see how it would apply to this situation.

Can someone provide an example or point me to a guide on this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to pass the physician ID to your `PatientsController#new` action. If users get there by folloing a link, this would be something like

```
<%= link_to 'Create an appointment', new_patient_path(:physician_id => @physician.id) %>
```

Or, if users have to submit a form, you can submit a hidden field with it:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :physician_id, @physician.id %>
```

Then, in `PatientsController#new`:

```
def new
  @patient = Patient.new
  @physician = Physician.find(params[:physician_id])
  @patient.appointments.build(:physician_id => @physician.id)
end
```

In `new.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for @patient do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :appointments do |ff |%>
    <%= ff.hidden_field :physician_id %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great.  I do have a question on setting the appointment time.  Would I add another field below the hidden field in your example for the appointment time?

Comment: Sure, you would set up your fields just as though it were another form, the only difference is that you use the methods of the form builder instance passed into the block to `fields_for`, so to add a date field, you'd do something like `<%= ff.input :appointment_time %>`.

Comment: BTW I had a mistake in my original post, `f.hidden_field` should've been `ff.hidden_field`. Corrected now.