# How to display records of table with associations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating table with Association source [as per this documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Here have three tables with association and relationship as follows

**Categor** table is the main table

**Product** table belongs to categor table where its product_id references categor(id)

**Sale** table belongs to Product table where its sale_id references product(id)

When I run the code migration, it was successful and I could display the content of categor table.

Now I want to also display content of **Product** and **sale** table as per this line of code

```
@prod = @categors.products.all
@sal = @prod.sales.all
```

but it shows error

```
undefine method products for #<Categor:ActiveRecord_Relation>
```

Here is the working migrations

**Categor Migrations**

```
class CreateCategors < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :categors do |t|
      #has_one :product
      #has_one :sale, :through => :product

      t.string :cat_name
      t.string :car_label

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Product Migration**

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.belongs_to :categor, index: true
      t.string :prod_name
      t.string :prod_desc

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Sale Migration**

```
class CreateSales < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :sales do |t|
      t.belongs_to :product, index: true

      t.string :sales_name
      t.string :sales_desc

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**categor_controller**

```
class CategorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_categor, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index

   @categors = Categor.all
   @prod = @categors.products.all
   @sal = @prod.sales.all
end
```

**update section**

```
class Categor < ApplicationRecord
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
end

class Sale < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Comment: also share the contents of 3 model files

Comment: You might be missing the `has_many` associations that correspond to those `belongs_to` associations you named (show your models though). https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.2/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association. Anyway, `Category.all` gives you ALL the categories, not just one, so `@categors.products` makes no sense, the associations works on objects, not on classes.

Comment: please can you see the updated section of post towards the bottom for models of the three tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reference [a suggestion found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473044/rails-4-many-to-many-association-not-working) and thus discovers that I need to add the association into all my models.

I also follow the comment of **arieljuod** when he said displaying all the `categor` data does not make sense.

So first at controller, I used `find()` method for table `categor` and `product` as per code below:

```
class CategorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_categor, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def index

   @categors = Categor.find(1)
   @prod = @categors.products.find_by_categor_id(1)
   @sal = @prod.sales.all
end
```

Here are my models:

```
class Categor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
  has_many :sales, :through => :products
end


class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :categor
  has_many :sales

end



class Sale < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :product
end
```

Comment: This differs from your initial question. Now you are working with an object and not with a `ActiveRecord_Relation`. You initial question looked like that you need all sales of all products which is in one Categor.

Comment: I tried your solution but. it still throws error map undefined

Answer (score 0):

Because `@prod` is a `ActiveRecord_Relation` you can't handle it directly.
You have to map or select the `sales`

```
@sal = @prod.each.map(&:sales)
```

or

```
@sal = Sale.where(product_id: @prod.ids)
```

for a `ActiveRecord_Relation`

Comment: it says undefine method map

Comment: `@prod.each.map(&:id)` can be shortened to `@prod.ids`