# many-to-many with has_many :through association nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, nested-forms, has-many-through, cocoon-gem

student.rb

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :courses, through: :enrollments

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :enrollments
end
```

enrollment.rb

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :course
end
```

course.rb

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollments
  has_many :students, through: :enrollments
end
```

enrollments_controller.rb

```
class EnrollmentsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @current_student = current_user.student
    @enrollments =  @current_student.enrollments.build
  end

  def create
    current_student = current_user.student
    @enrollments =  current_student.enrollments.build(enrollment_params)
      if @enrollments.save
          flash[:success] = "You have successfully enrolled."
          redirect_to new_enrollment_path
      else
          # fail
          flash[:danger] = "Please try again."
          redirect_to new_enrollment_path
      end
  end

  private
    def enrollment_params
        params.require(:enrollment).permit(:student_id, :course_id)
    end

end
```

enrollment/new.html.erb

```
<%= nested_form_for(@current_student, html: { class: 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :enrollments do |e| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= e.label :course_id, for: :course_id, class: 'col-xs-3 control-label' %>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
          <%= e.collection_select :course_id, Course.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select your Course"}, {class: 'form-control'} %>
        </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.link_to_add 'Add Course', :enrollments, class: "col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3" %>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-xs-9 col-xs-offset-3">
        <%= f.submit "Enroll Now", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
      </div>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

By referering to :

[many-to-many: has_many :through association form with data assigned to linking model create form view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480939/many-to-many-has-many-through-association-form-with-data-assigned-to-linking-m/11481404#11481404)

Intention: Create the **Enrollments** with the **existing** courses and students.

Current implementation of enrollment/new.html.erb will show all of the existing enrollments on the form which is not the desired presentation view.

I wish to create a blank form for creating enrollments.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By just adding a line, "!e.object.persisted?" it solves the problem.

enrollment/new.html.erb

```
<%= f.fields_for :enrollments do |e| %>

    <!--  -->
    <% if !e.object.persisted? %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= e.label :course_id, for: :course_id, class: 'col-xs-3 control-label' %>
          <div class="col-xs-9">
            <%= e.collection_select :course_id, Course.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Select your Course"}, {class: 'form-control'} %>
          </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That seems a bit weird: only show (or allow to edit) enrollments if they are new? Why do it with cocoon then, and not just create a new enrollment, and the user is given (known), as a hidden field. Also: now I understand your question, it was totally unclear to me before. An alternative test is `e.object.new_record?` which may or may not be clearer (it is to me, but that is probably personal :) )

Comment: @nathanvda, because in one single page, I would like to allow the user to create multiple enrollments. By using the cocoon/nested form, I would be able to have dynamic multiple Enrollment creation from the f.link_to_add scripting function. 

Thanks for your suggestion, I will try the alternative way "e.object.new_record?"